# Eclipse is not working after download

Tags: eclipse, download, log-files

I downloaded the eclipse from this site: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ (Eclipse classic 4.2.1)

I extracted the zip folder and ran the exe file -> eclipse (With the symbol of a circle of eclipse)

I get this error message: An error has occurred. see the log file...

I saw the log file is very long and not understood, I did not find the problem.

can anyone help me?

I think that the error that was written in the log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: can you post the error log ?

Comment: Log file is very long, I can not find the exact error there.

Comment: Write missing a lot of things, even though I downloaded it all as one package, perhaps missing something else needs an external download?

Comment: When looking at the .metadata\.log log file, look for something like 'error' or 'exception' backwards starting from the end of the file

Comment: According to Eclipse forum, you are missing some parts in launch settings: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/155457/ . However, you should not have such problem with clean "install" (quoted, as eclipse does not require installation). Try to remove the settings saved by Eclipse and relaunch it again.

Comment: Where can I remove the settings saved by eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try launching it as administrator.
or
try from DOS prompt.

or 
create the workspace folder in your home directory.

or

finally read log file.