# Errors in a log file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logfiles

Please see my previous question:

[Eclipse is not working after download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909468/eclipse-is-not-working-after-download)

I deleted the config folder, and when I pressed the eclipse is a new create a new and different problem:

On the log file appears the problem this way:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-12-17 10:27:25.247
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

What is this problem?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and running other variations of the IDE? Like RCP/RAP or the full EE IDE?

Comment: No, I have not tried it matter?

Comment: **Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, 227 MB** try downloading this one, see if you get the same error. :P If you have the time.

Comment: It gets the same error? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem:

I added to the config file the location of the JVM.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Thank you all for the help

Comment: This is actually very good to know. Thumbs up for your research. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the end of you `config.ini` file.

```
Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@
```

**Edit:**

Further reference [right here](http://www.volker-wegert.de/en/node/65#comment-197).

Comment: There are two config files one on the folder configuration and the other outside, where to put?

Comment: I searched for this file in the folder: org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench. Write on log file (on the first issue before I deleted the configuration folder) is missing, and he has really, that's the problem?

Comment: I downloaded from the site the whole package is not divided files, how could it be missing a file?

Comment: Damn dude... what OS are you using? I tend to think the problem lies with your computer, and not with the IDE.